Error Program exited with code -1073741819 - DerelictSDL2
I'm developing an application using SDL2 and SDL2_image in D, and I'm encountering an access violation error -1073741819 when I attempt to run my program. I've included the relevant code below. The error occurs when I try to initialize SDL2_image or when creating the window, but I am not certain which part is specifically causing the issue.
import std.stdio;
import derelict.sdl2.sdl;
import derelict.sdl2.image;

void main() {
    // Load SDL2 dynamically
    DerelictSDL2.load();

    // Initialize SDL_image for JPG support
    if (IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG) & (IMG_INIT_JPG != IMG_INIT_JPG)) {
        writeln("Failed to initialize SDL_image: ", SDL_GetError());
        return;
    }

    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        writeln("Failed to initialize SDL: ", SDL_GetError());
        return;
    }

    // Create window
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello SDL2",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window) {
        writeln("Failed to create window: ", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return;
    }

    // Create renderer with hardware acceleration and synchronized with the refresh rate
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (!renderer) {
        writeln("Failed to create renderer: ", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return;
    }

    // Load image and create texture
    SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load("fdcae74b5ad91e309aa03020c7ea4f26.jpg");
    if (!image) {
        writeln("Failed to load image: ", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return;
    }
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
    if (!texture) {
        writeln("Failed to create texture: ", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_FreeSurface(image);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return;
    }

    // Event handling loop
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

I've Ensured all libraries are correctly installed and paths are properly configured.
Added comprehensive error checks after each operation that interacts with SDL.
Verified that the image file exists and is accessible.

I know nothing about DerelictSDL2, but looking at the documentation I saw this:

Each of the satellite libraries has its own module and its own loader

With the following code snippet as an example:
import derelict.sdl2.image,
       derelict.sdl2.sdl;
void main() {
    DerelictSDL2.load();
    DerelictSDL2Image.load();
}

So, it seems to me that adding DerelictSDL2Image.load(); after DerelictSDL2.load(); in your code should fix the issue.
